# How to write unit test cases while using nestjs framework?

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am using the nestjs framework and I want to write the unit test cases for every service and controller.
I have gone through many examples on google but not found any solution.
Actually, I want to play with the real database without mocking any service and the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a real database connection, you're doing integration tests, not unit tests. A unit test mocks out the logic that isn't being immediately tested (external libraries, database calls, HTTP requests, etc), whereas an integration sometimes tests these, and sometimes just tests between classes without mocking those relationships.

[There's a large repository of samples you can find here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs). This repo has unit and e2e/integration tests. Without knowing more on what you want to test, there's not really more anyone can say other than "Generally here's how you do it" which the [docs already cover pretty well](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing)